# What is the best way to define a row vector in NumPy?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, vector

I'm relatively new to NumPy.

In Matlab, making a row vector was pretty simple.

```
 x = [1, 2, 3]
```

In NumPy, I think the following "y" is actually not a row vector.

```
 y = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

since it is one dimensional.
Additionally, the following "z" is a column vector not a row vector.

```
 z= np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
```

In NumPy, to do the same thing, how I can do it? One way is doing the following:

```
 x = np.array([[1], [2], [3]]).transpose()
```

But it looks somewhat absurd. 
Could anyone give some suggestions on this?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you explain what you are using the row vector for? Row vectors are not typically needed in Numpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "row vector" you mean a matrix (2d array) with 1 row, then you need

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3]])
```

or more easily

```
x1d = np.array([1,2,3])
x = x1d[None,:] #insert singleton dimension
```

Think of `ndarray`s as lists of lists (of list of lists of...). For a 2d array, each row is a list. Hence `[[1,2,3]]`. This also explains why you need to use `[[1],[2],[3]]` for a column.

But for almost any application a 1d `numpy` array is as good as a row vector. For columns, however, you do need to use something like `x1d[:,None]`.

The difference between the three kinds of variables:

```
In [496]: x1d.shape
Out[496]: (3,)

In [497]: x1d[None,:].shape
Out[497]: (1, 3)

In [498]: x1d[:,None].shape
Out[498]: (3, 1)
```

So often you don't have to use an explicit row vector but a 1d array will suffice. Most importantly, broadcasting of a 1d array works as with a 2d row vector:

```
In [501]: x1d+np.ones((3,3))
Out[501]: 
array([[ 2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.]])

In [502]: x1d[None,:]+np.ones((3,3))
Out[502]: 
array([[ 2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply go with

```
x = np.array([1,2,3]).reshape((1,3))
```

or if you want to create x from a list, `y=[1,2,3]`, then

```
x = np.array(y).reshape((1,len(y))
```